# Are countable nouns always in plural in recipes' names?

Tags: grammatical-number, food

I have the following ingredients in a recipe:

> 40 g  oat flakes
>
> 150 ml milk (1.5% milkfat)
>
> 4 g butter
>
> ½ apple, grated

I need to know if I should name the recipe

> Oat Flakes with **Apples**

or

> Oat Flakes with **Apple**

Most recipes I've found use always plural with countable nouns, e.g.

> Grilled Chicken with Apples
>
> Chinese Long Bean Salad with Tangerines
>
> Mixed Green Salad with Pears

But it seems weird to me to use "Apples" when the recipe uses only one half of apple.

Comment: You could also say Apple Oat Flakes.

Comment: 'Apple' is not a count noun in 'Oat Flakes with Apple'. Many nouns offer both options. But I'd perhaps avoid  'Oat Flake with Apple', and certainly 'Rice Krispie with Marshmallow'.

Comment: Of the two I'd go with "Oat flakes with Apple", 'apples' signifies a multitude of apples. 'Apple' in this context doesn't actually mean "one apple", it means "some undetermined amount of apple" and could mean anything from a slice of apple to 200 apples. Perfect for putting in a title :)

Comment: @Born2Smile: I misread your comment. I thought you said "perfect for putting in a trifle". (Some apples, some trifle!).

Comment: @Margana, ooh yum! :D

Answer (score 0):

I can't find advice for this in the AP Stylebook. Either apple or apples should be acceptable, except that, to me,

1. "Oat Flakes with Apple" sounds like corporate-speak for "with apple flavoring," and "Oat Flakes with Apples" sounds more like Marketeering English for "with bits of real apple."
2. If you were to make 20 batches of this recipe commercially, it would indeed be Oat Flakes with Apples. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Apple" is countable when it's, well, *an* apple.
As you suspect, when that apple is reduced to pieces, gratings, pulp, etc, it loses its countability (how could you count it/them?).

So if you say *oat flakes with apples*, it implies that the apples are whole. Since the apple in your recipe is grated, then the dish is *oat flakes with apple*.

Goodness knows where I can find a reference for this claim. I'll have a look now...

Comment: I'm not sure that you'd really say "with apple" instead of "with apples" just because you're not sure how many apples are in it.  Consider "peas and carrots" or "scalloped potatoes", for example.

Comment: Yes, I would. Oh, but not with peas. Hmm. I'd happily say "with apple," "with carrot", or "with potato", (if these were, say, grated). So what is it with "pea"? I'd say "pea puree". Oh dear... I'd say "soup with pea and ham (I think). But not "soup with pea". Or "bean", come to that. I'd say "with cabbage2, but not "with brussels sprout". Ooer.

Comment: _I'm not sure that you'd really say "with apple" instead of "with apples" just because you're not sure how many apples are in it._ That wasn't the point I was trying to make, though. I was suggesting that when an ingredient is processed, and loses its identity, it becomes uncountable. I'm quite happy to refer to peas and carrots when they remain whole (or even sliced, but that's tricky, and those peas still bother me even when they're mashed).